# How to interact with selenium web driver (safari) without stopping automation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I had to do a captcha to sign into something. Is there a way where I could do the captcha without stopping automation. When I click the browser, it asks if I'd like to stop automation. (In python)